# How to read csv file to numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, csv, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to read my `csv-file` into an ndarrays.

myfile.csv

```
user,latitude,longitude
500,39.984608,116.317761
500,39.984563,116.317517
500,39.984539,116.317294
605,26.16167,119.943128
605,26.161566,119.942352
605,26.161558,119.942401
745,22.814336,108.332281
745,22.81429,108.3322566
745,22.81432,108.3322583
```

my code:

```
import numpy as np
my_data = np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=True)

type(my_data)
numpy.ndarray

print(my_data)
[[500.         39.984608  116.317761 ]
 [500.         39.984563  116.317517 ]
 [500.         39.984539  116.317294 ]
 [605.         26.16167   119.943128 ]
 [605.         26.161566  119.942352 ]
 [605.         26.161558  119.942401 ]
 [745.         22.814336  108.332281 ]
 [745.         22.81429   108.3322566]
 [745.         22.81432   108.3322583]]
```

However, my intented output is to get an arrays of array, each array for one user, so that the output is:

```
[
  [[500.         39.984608  116.317761 ]
   [500.         39.984563  116.317517 ]
   [500.         39.984539  116.317294 ]]
  [[605.         26.16167   119.943128 ]
   [605.         26.161566  119.942352 ]
   [605.         26.161558  119.942401 ]]
  [[745.         22.814336  108.332281 ]
   [745.         22.81429   108.3322566]
   [745.         22.81432   108.3322583]]
]
```

How do I rewrite my code to do this?

Comment: @arilwan yes sure I did. But all the answers their about numpy to ndarray, not doing nesting as in the example output I want

Comment: Exactly, each array corresponds to one user records.

Comment: Always 3 records for each user?  If so just reshape to (-1, 3,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will give you a `numpy.ndarray` partitioned by the first column of `my_data`. If order matters, you can sort either `partition_values` in the comprehension, or sort `grouped_values`.

```
import numpy as np


my_data = np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=True)
partition_values = {row[0] for row in my_data}
grouped_data = np.array([my_data[my_data[:,0] == pvalue, :]
                         for pvalue in partition_values])
```

Comment: @Michael Ruth sorry to get back on this answer please. It seems I'm losing the shape of the nested arrays, which need for later processing: `grouped_data.shape`
`(3,)` inner arrays have 2 columns for `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: @super_ask, I get `grouped_data.shape (3, 3, 3)` when I run the code above. Under which conditions are you running this code? Mine are as follows:
macOS 10.15.3, python 3.7.6, numpy 1.16.4.

Comment: @Micheal Ruth This happens after I add one more entry to id 500, as my inner arrays might be of of different length, depending on trip time.

Comment: @super_ask, Unfortunately, this is a limitation of shape. There is no tuple that can represent the shape of the array you describe. The only candidates are (3, 3, 3) and (3, 4, 3), but the first is correct only if the data for user 500 are removed and the latter is correct only if the data for users 605 and 745 are removed. The best you can do with multidimensional arrays with non-uniform shape is to iterate over the component arrays and get their shape, e.g. [group.shape for group in grouped_data].

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def getArraysofArray(my_data):
    FinalList=[]
    temp=[]
    for i in range(len(my_data)):
        if(i==0):
            temp.append(my_data[i])
            continue
        if(my_data[i][0]!=my_data[i-1][0]):
            FinalList.append(temp)
            temp=[]
        if(my_data[i]==my_data[-1]):
            FinalList.append(temp)
        temp.append(my_data[i])
    return FinalList

# Main / Testing of Function
my_data=[[500,39.984608 ,116.317761]
 ,[500,39.984563,116.317517]
 ,[500,39.984539,116.317294]
 ,[605,26.16167,119.943128]
 ,[605,26.161566,119.942352]
 ,[605,26.161558,119.942401]
 ,[745,22.814336,108.332281]
 ,[745,22.81429,108.3322566]
 ,[745,22.81432,108.3322583]]
list=getArraysofArray(my_data)
print(list)
# Output
[[[500, 39.984608, 116.317761], [500, 39.984563, 116.317517], [500, 39.984539, 116.317294]],
 [[605, 26.16167, 119.943128], [605, 26.161566, 119.942352], [605, 26.161558, 119.942401]],
 [[745, 22.814336, 108.332281], [745, 22.81429, 108.3322566], [745, 22.81432, 108.3322583]]]
```